# RoleExistsAsync always returning false despite roles being seeded in .NET Core 8 Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm encountering an issue with role management in my .NET Core 8 Web API project using Identity for authentication. I have successfully seeded roles to the database during the OnModelCreating method, as shown below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Seed User Roles
    SeedRoles(builder);
}

private void SeedRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_Admin },
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_User },
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_HR });
}
```

However, when I attempt to check if a role exists using await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role) in my controller, it always returns false, even when the role name is present in the database.

I have verified that the roles are indeed seeded to the database. Here's the relevant code snippet from the controller:

```
var roleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role);
```

Any insights into why RoleExistsAsync is not recognizing the seeded roles would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by initializing the NormalizedName field of the IdentityRole objects during seeding. Update your code as follows:

```
private void SeedRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_Admin, ConcurrencyStamp = "1",     NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_User, ConcurrencyStamp = "2", NormalizedName = "USER" },
        new IdentityRole { Name = SD.Role_HR, ConcurrencyStamp = "3",     NormalizedName = "HR" });
}
```

This ensures that the NormalizedName field is set correctly, and RoleExistsAsync should now recognize the seeded roles.